# Is an int variable an object, according to the C++ Standard?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

Below you'll find the definition of object in C++ Standard.

[[intro.object]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/intro.object#1):

> The constructs in a C++ program create, destroy, refer to, access, and
>   manipulate objects. An *object* is created by a definition (6.1), by a
>   *new-expression* (8.3.4), when implicitly changing the active member of a union (12.3), or when a temporary object is created (7.4, 15.2).
>   An object occupies a region of storage in its period of construction
>   (15.7), throughout its lifetime (6.8), and in its period of
>   destruction (15.7). [ Note: A function is not an object, regardless of
>   whether or not it occupies storage in the way that objects do. —end
>   note ] The properties of an object are determined when the object is
>   created. An object can have a name (Clause 6). An object has a storage
>   duration (6.7) which influences its lifetime (6.8). An object has a
>   type (6.9). Some objects are polymorphic (13.3); the implementation
>   generates information associated with each such object that makes it
>   possible to determine that object’s type during program execution. For
>   other objects, the interpretation of the values found therein is
>   determined by the type of the *expressions* (Clause 8) used to access
>   them.

I have a feeling that yes, an `int` variable can be considered an object in C++, notwithstanding this statement in the paragraph above:

> An object occupies a region of storage in its period of construction
>   (15.7), throughout its lifetime (6.8), and in its period of
>   destruction (15.7).

There are several other statements in the Standard that seem to assume that the term *object* is restricted to class objects. Thus, for the sake of precision, I'm posting this question.

Comment: It is unclear why you think an `int` could be considered *not* to be an object based on what you posted.

Comment: C++ standard's `object` has nothing to do with _"Object Orientated"_.  It is just a region of storage. An `int` being a region of storage is therefore an `object` so it a float, char etc.

Comment: @juanchopanza `An object occupies a region of storage in its period of construction (15.7), throughout its lifetime (6.8), and in its period of destruction (15.7).`. Well, `int` objects are not constructed nor destructed.

Comment: @JoãoAfonso They are, conceptually.

Comment: @Richard Critten: From "an object occupies storage" we must not conclude that "everything occupying storage is an object". It seems we are all confident that an `int` is an object, but does the standard somewhere *define* the term object rather than just  *describing* properties of them?

Comment: Is a DR appropriate here? I feel like this should be really clear and obvious. Even adding something like `int x; // 'x' is an object` as an example under [intro.object]/1 would be beneficial IMHO.

Comment: @VittorioRomeo I would say so. But I'll leave that to the experts to judge. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @StephanLechner _"An object, in C++, is a region of storage that has..."_ http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/object  Also _"A variable is an object or a reference that is not a non-static data member, that is introduced by a declaration."_ same link.

Answer (score 6):

**Yes, an `int` is an *object*.**

All the sentences in the quote you posted are valid and true for `int` variables.

Additionally, here are some examples that show how `int` makes sense for the quote you posted:

---

> An object is created by a definition

From [[basic.def]](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.def):

> ```
> int a;                          // defines a
> ```

Suggesting that `int` is an object.

---

> An object has a type

From [[basic.types]](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.types):

> There are two kinds of types: fundamental types and compound types.

`int` is a [fundamental type](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.fundamental). This again suggests that `int` is an object.

Comment: Logical  fallacy? Object created by definition does not imply something created by a definition is an object.

Comment: Along the same lines, an object having a type does not *prove* that everything with a type is an object.

Comment: @juanchopanza: you're correct. I reworded my answer.

Comment: @juanchopanza But the second statement, `There are two kinds of types: fundamental types and compound types.` seems to show that an `int` is an object in C++.

Comment: @JoãoAfonso Ehm, no, it is the same logical fallacy. All As have property X doesn't mean all things with property X are an A.

Comment: @juanchopanza I can see what you mean. The fact that an object has a type and that there are two kinds of types (fundamental and compound types), that doesn't allow us to conclude that an `int` is an object.

Answer (score 0):

Even though the standard doesn't enumerate everything that are objects, it can be deduced from various paragraphs. From [[basic.types]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.types#1)

> [basic.types] and the subclauses thereof impose requirements on implementations regarding the representation of types. There are two kinds of types: fundamental types and compound types. Types describe objects, references, or functions.

And [[basic.types]/8](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.types#8)

> An object type is a (possibly cv-qualified) type that is not a function type, not a reference type, and not cv void.

Since `int` is not a [reference type](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.ref) nor a [function type](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.fct), it is deduced `int` can only be an object type, and a variable declared thus is an object.

Answer (score 0):

According to [isocpp.org](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/classes-and-objects#overview-object):

> What is an object?
>
> A region of storage with associated semantics.
>
> **After the declaration int i; we say that “i is an object of type int.**”
> In OO/C++, “object” usually means “an instance of a class.” Thus a
> class defines the behavior of possibly many objects (instances).

But the type int is not an object. Check [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/object).

> The following entities are not objects: value, reference, function,
> enumerator, **type**, non-static class member, template, class or function
> template specialization, namespace, parameter pack, and this.